Can 3rd order intercept point be used to extrapolate the power of 3rd harmonic or 3rd order intermodulation distortion at an arbitrary input power?
I'm trying to understand how to interpret 3rd Order Intercept (OIP3) specifications, and whether or not I can use them to extrapolate performances characteristics, other than just as a measure of relative linearity.
The motivation for this question is that I'm trying to figure out what the expected power level of a 3rd order intermodulation product would be for a specific input power level of two equal power carrier signals.  For example, in the case of a system with a preamplifier to a radio receiver with a known receive threshold, what would the power of two input signals have to be for their 3rd Order Intermodulation (IMD3) product to exceed the receiver threshold (assuming that the IM3 is on frequency of the receiver).
My thinking is that since the input vs output slope of the 1st order fundamental is 1:1 and the 3rd order is 3:1, then I should be able to plot both lines to determine the output power of the 3rd order signal vs the arbitrary power level of the input signal.  Also, I believe that IM3 follows the dBm_in vs dBm_out slope as the 3rd Order harmonic.
So in the example plot below, a receiver preamplifier has a gain of +30 db, an OIP3 of +45dBm, and a receive sensitivity threshold of -118 dBm.  The blue line which represents the input vs output of two equal carrier signals is plotted with a 1:1 slope, while the red line that represents the IMD3 is plotted at a 3:1 slope.
According to the plots, the IMD3 produced by two input signals, f1 and f2, both at -39.3 dBm will exceed the receiver sensitivity threshold of -118 dBm, and assuming it's on frequency will be “heard” by the receiver.
So, is it valid to plot the 3rd Order characteristics this way, or is the 3:1 slope only valid closer to the OIP3 region, where the amplifier starts behaving non-linearly?


To answer shortly, yes, it does.
The whole point of an IP3 point is to be able to report it by itself, whereas any IMD3/2 numbers must always be reported with its corresponding fundamental output amplitude.
Obviously, by doing this calculation, you're implicitly assuming that your amplifier is the weakly non-linear region, i.e. 2nd order sidebands have 2dB per dB increase and the 3rd order a 3dB per.
A common way to show whether your assumption is correct is to measure the IP3 at your frequency of interest as a function of the input signal amplitude. In general, you should expect a constant line at low input levels and a collapse at high levels due to compression. Of course, you have to make sure your equipments IP3 is a lot better than your DUT, and there are ways to check that.

The OIP3 model tends only to be valid at low signal levels. As the signal level rises and approaches the compression point of the amplifier, the amplifier distorts more strongly, the order of distortion increases, and the OIP3 model stops working.
For any given amplifier, before you can use OIP3 to estimate distortion levels, you need to know to what maximum signal level it's valid. Measure distortion versus signal level and plot them on a graph, and see where the curve deviates from the nice theoretical 3:1 ratio. Use it below this level. Extrapolate the straight lines portion of the graph to their intercept at the OIP3 level.
Hint, with good amplifiers it's often quite difficult to measure OIP3, as you are often fighting the IP3 of the signal sources and the measuring equipment.
The OIP3 is not a level an amplifier can ever reach, it will limit waaaaaay below the OIP3 level. It's merely a number that happens to have units of dBm that you plug into the OIP3 model to predict the levels of the third order distortion that the amplifier is always producing.

Yes, I totally see your point about OIP being a theorical point that will never be reached.  But I'm asking about  low level signal, within operating range.  I'm trying to figure out if it makes sense that a -39.3 dBm signal will result in -118 dBm  3rd order response?  That's what the plots show, based on the OIP3 and 3:1 slope.

@Frank I think you've done your sums wrong. For +45 dBm IP3, -9 dBm signals will give you IPs 2x(45-(-9)) = 108 dB below signals = -118 dBm.
